# What is the best way to plot confidence intervals for close curves

Tags: python, matplotlib, confidence-interval, errorbar

I have to plot a figure that contains three curves that are close to each other. When I plot the confidence intervals in each curve, I get an ugly figure that contains confidence intervals that are overlapped.

Here is an example.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


y1 = [2, 3.9, 5.8, 7.2]
y2 = [2, 3.7, 5.6, 7.1]
y3 = [1.9, 3.6, 5.4, 6.8]
x = [2, 4, 6, 8]

ci1 = 1.96 * np.std(y1)/np.sqrt(len(x))
ci2 = 1.96 * np.std(y2)/np.sqrt(len(x))
ci3 = 1.96 * np.std(y3)/np.sqrt(len(x))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y1)
ax.fill_between(x, (y1-ci1), (y1+ci1), color='b', alpha=.1)

ax.plot(x, y2)
ax.fill_between(x, (y2-ci2), (y2+ci2), color='b', alpha=.1)

ax.plot(x, y3)
ax.fill_between(x, (y3-ci3), (y3+ci3), color='b', alpha=.1)

plt.show()
```

[image]
Do you know of any better way to show the curves with the confidence intervals? I tried with error bars but it is even uglier. Is it a good alternative to show the confidence intervals in the legend or some where in the x- or y-axis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about your confidence interval being constant along the x-axis.

Your data should have multiple points for each x values, then you have a confidence interval for each x value, something like this:

```py
import numpy as np

x = [2, 4, 6, 8]
num_x = len(x)
num_y = 20

y1 = np.array([2, 3.9, 5.8, 7.2])
y2 = np.array([2, 3.7, 5.6, 7.1])
y3 = np.array([1.9, 3.6, 5.4, 6.8])

# Multiple points for each x values
y1 = np.stack([y1 for _ in range(num_y)], axis=0)
y2 = np.stack([y2 for _ in range(num_y)], axis=0)
y3 = np.stack([y3 for _ in range(num_y)], axis=0)

# Some randomness for CI
y1 = y1 + np.random.randn(*y1.shape)
y2 = y2 + np.random.randn(*y2.shape)
y3 = y3 + np.random.randn(*y3.shape)
```

For your actual question, maybe you can plot individual boxes for each point of each curve:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Tweaks the position so no overlapping
num_curves = 3
pos1 = np.arange(1, (num_curves + 1) * num_x + 1, num_curves + 1)
pos2 = np.arange(2, (num_curves + 1) * num_x + 2, num_curves + 1)
pos3 = np.arange(3, (num_curves + 1) * num_x + 3, num_curves + 1)

# But then fix the ticks
xticks = [2, 6, 10, 14]
xtickslabels = [1, 2, 3, 4]

bplot1 = ax.boxplot(y1, positions=pos1, patch_artist=True)
bplot2 = ax.boxplot(y2, positions=pos2, patch_artist=True)
bplot3 = ax.boxplot(y3, positions=pos3, patch_artist=True)

ax.set_xticks(xticks)
ax.set_xticklabels(xtickslabels)

bplots = (bplot1, bplot2, bplot3)
colors = ["pink", "lightblue", "lightgreen"]
for bplot, clr in zip(bplots, colors):
    for patch in bplot["boxes"]:
        patch.set_facecolor(clr)

plt.show()
```

[image: boxplot]

Comment: Very good idea to use boxes. Thank you. About my confidence intervals being constant, I actually showed only my avereged data points. Thank you again.

Comment: I have one question: what are the circle shown in the figure? As I understand, the colours bars are the data 20 values for y. The error bars are shown for each y. But what are the circles?

Comment: I used [`boxplot`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.boxplot.html) which by default shows a box from Q1 to Q3, the median, and the circles are outliers. You could also use [`violinplot`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.violinplot.html) with the same idea of shifting overlaping points.  Btw this is implemented in seaborn as [`so.Dodge`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.objects.Dodge.html), and maybe just plot all your data as [shown here](https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/jitter_stripplot.html) which is often the best.

Comment: Plotting all the data is often the most honest approach, especially if there's this few points.  Matplotlib box plots have bad defaults, e.g. too much weight at the ends of the whiskers and outliers.  See https://statmodeling.stat.columbia.edu/2006/01/04/the_difference_1/ for a semirelated read & academic paper